# Product of random variables. Need help.

Tags: probability

A coin is thrown three times. Let X be a random variable that accounts for number of fallen heads, and Y for number of fallen tails. Find the distribution of P{XY}
 Answer"
$$R_{XY}= \{ 0,2\}$$
$$P\{ XY=0\}=P\{(X,Y)=(0,3) \}+ P\{(X,Y)=(3,0)\}= 1/4$$
$$P\{ XY=2\}=P\{(X,Y)=(1,2) \}+ P\{(X,Y)=(2,1)\}= 3/4$$

How is it 1/4 and 3/4 ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 8 possible outcomes for the sequence of 3 throws, all of which are equally likely.  FOr example, HHH, HTH, TTH. TTT, all of these share the same probability of $\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^3 = \frac18$.

Of these, one is HHH and one is TTT and those are the only ways $XY$ can be zero.
So 
$$P(XT=0) = \frac18 + \frac18 = \frac14$$

The reset all have $XY = 2$ and their probabiolities add to 
$$
1 - \frac14 = \frac34$$

Comment: How about this one: a dice is thrown twice. If both throws show a even number, the dice is thrown again.. : $X-$number of 4's in the two trows, $Y$- numbers of 5's in the two throws. $P\{ (X,Y)=(0,0) \}={12\over 36}+{16 \over 216}$ but I get $P\{ (X,Y)=(0,0) \}={16\over 36}+{8 \over 216}$

Comment: and $P\{ (X,Y)=(1,0) \}={4\over 36}+{24 \over 216}$ but I get

Comment: $P\{ (X,Y)=(1,0) \}={8\over 36}+{24 \over 216}$

Comment: I understand now, no need..